# Analytic Tableaux Smullyan's Style

Tags: tables, trees, logic

Is there a simple and intuitive way to drawn with latex this kind of tree?[image]

I tried to check in the site "LATEX for LOGICIANS", but I can't find this kind of tree, with this kind of layout. 
Thank you

Comment: Section 4 of the [LaTeX for Logicians](http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/trees/) site appears to have **exactly** this type of tree.

Comment: I saw it, but I would like to find the latex code of that kind of type...

Comment: Well, if you look at the packages listed on that page, you will find plenty of examples. There are also examples on this site. This is just standard. You don't even need numbers or labelling, which is where the complications begin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a **forest** style, `smullyan tableaux`. The key `closed` can be used when the style is active to close the current branch.

One advantage of **forest** is the concise bracket syntax used to specify trees.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\newcommand*\lif{\mathbin{\to}}% added thanks to egreg's suggestion
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  smullyan tableaux/.style={
    for tree={
      math content
    },
    where n children=1{
      !1.before computing xy={l=\baselineskip},
      !1.no edge
    }{},
    closed/.style={
      label=below:$\times$
    },
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  smullyan tableaux
  [\lnot(\lnot(A \land B) \lif (\lnot A \lor \lnot B))
    [\lnot(A \land B)
      [\lnot(\lnot A \lor \lnot B)
        [\lnot\lnot A
          [\lnot\lnot B
            [A
              [B
                [\lnot A, closed]
                [\lnot B, closed]
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Smullyan tableaux]

Note that it is more usual in logic, as far as I know, to draw trees so that branches start from a common point:

[image: common branch point]

This can be achieved, if necessary, by adding

```
      parent anchor=south,
      child anchor=north,
```

to the style.

Comment: I usually define `\newcommand{\lto}{\mathbin{\to}}` so the arrow is treated as a binary operation (which it is, in this case).

Comment: @egreg I don't think it is really the correct arrow. When I had to draw these, I was using the horseshoe so it wasn't a problem.

Comment: @egreg Is that better? I think `\lif` is better than `\lto` because it can be redefined to `\supset` if necessary. (I know `\lto` could be also, but `\lif` is semantic whereas `\lto` is format.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple code with `pstricks`, and more specifically with `pst-tree`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-tree, auto-pst-pdf}
\def\noedge{\ncline[linestyle = none]}
\renewcommand\psedge{\ncline[arrows =-]}

\begin{document}

\centering
\[ \psset{levelsep=1.2cm, treesep=2cm, nodesepA=10pt, nodesepB=2pt}
    \pstree%
    {\TR[vref =-1.25]{%
        \makebox[0pt]{$ \begin{matrix}\neg(\neg(A\wedge B)\to(\neg A\vee\neg B))\\
            \neg(A\wedge B)\\
            \neg(\neg A\vee\neg B) \\
            \neg\neg A\\
            \neg\neg B\\
            A\\B\end{matrix} $}}}%
    {%
        \TR[vref=1, href=2]{$ \begin{matrix} \neg A\\ \times\end{matrix}$}
        \TR[vref=1, href=-2]{$ \begin{matrix} \neg B\\ \times \end{matrix}$}
        } \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help!